# Irregular shape drawing with css (should be responsive)

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

Is there any way to draw a shape (image below) with css? The grey border style should be **dashed**. And **the most important** is it should be **responsive** (**should adapt different size of screen with different radius**).

Bad example （not responsive）:

```css
#box {
    position: relative;
    margin: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px dashed #333;
}

.corner {
    position: absolute;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border: 1px dashed #333;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.top-left {
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    border-radius: 0 0 100% 0;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
    <div class="corner top-left"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: What is the background? Is it both the same color inside and outside the shape and is it a solid color?

Comment: @gonewithsin atleast try some code and show us what you have tried.

Comment: The background is white, the border is grey. In fact, it's just a question about how to draw a border like that image.

Comment: I just used a image instead of css or svg... I don't think that's a good way. So I want to make it with css, but I have no ideas about how to begin with this shape...

Comment: You cannot use the accepted answer in the link provided by @Jeremy but you can use the other circle based approaches. The radial gradient one cannot produce dashed borders.

Comment: @Harry yes, I was reading the answers.

Comment: @GoneWithSin: Ok, I am proceeding to close the question as you've found your solution. If you can't make it work for whatever reason you can edit this question and submit for re-opening (or) ask a new question.

Comment: None of those solutions seem 100%. They all impose hurdles for you one way or another (one can't dash, the other can only dash the top and bottom, the other has to have a square background, this one and that one have gobs of markup and CSS). This could be whipped up in an SVG in a minute or two... https://jsfiddle.net/6r0hhfsh/

Comment: @BitwiseCreative yes. It seems SVG is the only way...

Comment: @Harry Still not find a perfect way to solve it.

Comment: @GoneWithSin: Can you include the code that you had tried and also indicate why it was not perfect? Please [edit] the question and I'll get it reopened for you. Also, did you have a look at Bitwise Creative's answer? Did it not help you?

Comment: @Harry yes, it helps. My answer and Bitwise Creative's answer are both not responsive. The most important is the radius of the corner may changes with different size of screen. I have edited the question but it's not open...

Comment: @GoneWithSin: It wont automatically re-open after an edit. One among myself or other users with the re-open privilege have to vote for it to be re-opened. It would be better if you include your code in question because otherwise even if it gets re-opened, it would be closed quickly for lack of visible effort.

Comment: If this could be an answer : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/WxNPzO and that you add some of code and tries , maybe it could be voted to be reopen ...

Comment: @GCyrillus your answer helps a lot. It's the best answer till now. But the size of left top corner's border is still strange when width changes. I'm working on this.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to go with SVG. It's what it's for. Here's an example...

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 256 128" enable-background="new 0 0 256 128" xml:space="preserve">
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#828282" stroke-dasharray="10" stroke-width="5" d="M249.75,121h-242V64c0,0,56.5,4.75,56.5-56.5h185.5V121z" />
</svg>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6r0hhfsh/

Answer (score 0):

I go with an answer since it seems my comment brought you some ideas.

The idea is based on ([codepen](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/WxNPzO))

- Percentage vertical margin and padding to use width as reference.

  > https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties
- A background-gradient to draw the dashed curved (firefox is buggy there with dotted/dashed round borders)

  > https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=382721
- mix-blend-mode to blend pseudos parent and white background with the page.

  > https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode
  >
  > http://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode
- calc() to mix  percentage and pixel to draw the curved border at around 15-20px width.

  > https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-notation

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px;
  text-align:justify;
}

div {
  font-size:2em;
  width: 80%;
  background: white;
  margin: 10% 2em 2em 10%;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 15px dashed gray;
  position: relative;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

div:before {
  padding: calc(3% + 10px);
  float: left;
  content: '';
}

div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  padding: 7%;
  border: inherit;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: calc(-10% - 7px);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px white, inset 0 0 0 150px white;
}

div + div:after {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/250/250/people/6) center ;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px white;
}

p:before {
  content: '';
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: calc(7% + 35px);
  position: absolute;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 0, transparent 20px, gray 20px, gray 45px) bottom right no-repeat ;
  background-size: 35% 39.5%;
  top: -20px;;
  left: -20px;
  margin: -10%
}

body {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/640/480/nature/6) yellow;
  background-size: cover
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
    lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
    facilisis luctus, metus</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
    lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
    facilisis luctus, metus</p>
</div>
```